# "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory" when trying to move a file from temp

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I'm trying to move a file from the tmp directory, but it's not working as expected. Here's the code i have, and the log:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSLog(@"URL: %@", URL);

NSString *finalPath = [self fullPathForMediaDisplayType:JMediaDisplayTypeMovie];

NSLog(@"Final Path: %@", finalPath);

NSURL *finalURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalPath];

NSLog(@"Final URL: %@", finalURL);

NSError *error;
[fileManager removeItemAtURL:finalURL error:&error];
[fileManager moveItemAtURL:URL toURL:finalURL error:&error];

NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
```

Log:

```
URL: file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/APP-ID-REMOVED/tmp//trim.ptltHA.MOV
Final Path: /var/mobile/Applications/APP-ID-REMOVED/Documents/9i3bqQVsKZMXwjCr38My-movie.MOV
Final URL: file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/APP-ID-REMOVED/Documents/9i3bqQVsKZMXwjCr38My-movie.MOV
Error: error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)" UserInfo=0x1f53fb30 {NSUnderlyingError=0x1f53fad0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory", NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Applications/APP-ID-REMOVED/Documents/9i3bqQVsKZMXwjCr38My-movie.mov, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Remove
)}
```

Any ideas why this isn't recognising the directory? The documents directory definitely exists, I save all sorts of other files in there.

Comment: assuming a file already exists at "`finalURL`", what's the error returned right after your call to "`removeItemAtURL`"?

Comment: The `URL` has a double slash near the end. That needs to be fixed.

Comment: Looks to me like there is no file at `finalURL`, and the error you log is the one from the `removeItemAtURL:` call. Check the BOOLs returned for each call, I bet the first one fails (no such file yet) and the second worked fine.